# Dependent Picklist to show the names of the Cities on Selecting the Country

Tags: visualforce

I have 4 objects Country,State,District,City where State has a Master Detail relationship with Country as the master,District has a Master Detail relationship with State as the master and City has a Master Detail relationship with District as the master
My Requirement is to create a dependent picklist where while selectingthe value of the country picklist all the names will be displayed in the City picklist.I have used the following piece of code but I am not able to get the Cities in the picklist .Please guide me

```
<apex:page controller="Example3ctrl">
<apex:form >
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>
            <span></span>
            <apex:selectList styleClass="small" value="{!SelectedCountry}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <!--<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!showfields}" rerender="form"/>-->
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!Country}"/>
            </apex:selectList>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <label>
            <span></span>      
            <apex:selectList styleClass="small" value="{!SelectedCity}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!City}"/>
            </apex:selectList>
        </label>
    </div>
</apex:form>
```

```
Public with sharing class Example3ctrl{
Public Id   SelectedCountry{get;set;}
Public Id   SelectedCity{get;set;}

public Example3ctrl() {

}

public static List<SelectOption> getCountry() {
    system.debug('CountryOptions ');
    List<SelectOption> CountryOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    List<Country__c> Countrylist =new List<Country__c>(); 
    Countrylist = [Select Id,Name FROM Country__c];
    CountryOptions.add(new SelectOption('--None--','Country'));
    for (Country__c c :Countrylist ){
         CountryOptions.add(new SelectOption(c.Id,c.name));
    }

    //CountryOptions.sortOrder();      
 return CountryOptions ;    
 }

 public List<SelectOption> getCity() {

     system.debug('SelectedCountry@@@'+SelectedCountry);
     system.debug('CityOptions');
     List<SelectOption> CityOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
     List<City__c> Citylist = new List<City__c>();
     //List<Country__c> Countrylist = new List<Country__c>();
     Citylist = [Select Id,Name FROM City__c  where district__r.state__r.country__r.ID =:SelectedCountry];
     system.debug('@@@@Citylist'+Citylist);
     CityOptions.add(new SelectOption('--None--','City'));
     system.debug('CityOptions@@@'+CityOptions);
     for (City__c c : Citylist ) {
         system.debug('Inside for');
         CityOptions.add(new SelectOption(c.Id,c.Name));
         system.debug(CityOptions);
     }
     system.debug('CityOptions@@@@@'+CityOptions);
     //CityOptions.sortorder();
     return CityOptions;    
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks correct. You just need do rerender the child to get records.
Add Id in form and rerender your apex:form you will get record.

```
<div class="form-row">
    <label>
        <span></span>      
        <apex:selectList styleClass="small" value="{!SelectedCity}" multiselect="false" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!City}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
    </label>
</div>
```

Also you can do `.country__c =:SelectedCountry` this will give you same result.

Comment: Tushar Sharma . I did exactly as you suggested and it is working properly now.Thank you